# Show custom message under every shipping option on checkout page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, shipping-methods

I have Successfully Created a module for custom message on shipping method but i am not able to retrieve those data under the shipping method on checkout page, please help me.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

> add argument **view_model** inside block of your layout file

```
<arguments>
     <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">PackageName\ModuleName\ViewModel\CustomText</argument>
</arguments>
```

> add viewModel **CustomText.php**

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\ModuleName\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class CustomText implements ArgumentInterface
{
    const CUSTOM_COMMENT = 'custom_data/general/custom_message';
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getCustomText($scope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CUSTOM_COMMENT, $scope);
    }
}
```

> use viewModel in template(phtml) file

```
<?php
use PackageName\ModuleName\ViewModel\CustomText;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage; /** path of block class which you defined in layout.xml 
as example:
 <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="checkout.custom" template="Codilar_CustomCheckout::customMsg.phtml" cacheable="false">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Codilar\CustomCheckout\ViewModel\CustomText</argument>
       </arguments>
 </block> this comment is just for explain the usage */
/** @var Onepage $block */
/** @var $viewModel CustomText */
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
$customText = $viewModel->getCustomText();
?>
<h1><?= $customText ?></h1>
```

*I hope it will be Helpful*

Comment: It's Not Working Manav

Comment: @HemantKumar i have updated the answer, please try now, also check sortOrder in your module's system.xml file